# Search bar that searches SQL database then displays results form database - C# & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, nhibernate, searchbar

Here is my js.

Apologizes for not being more specific, learning as well how to use this site. my first answer is: my js is wrong. it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#search-now').click(function () {
    var SEARCHY = $('#prodId').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: { "search": SEARCHY },
        url: '/Search/Find',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
        });
});
```

});

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? You haven't explained the problem.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot? Have you confirmed your button calls your script? Have you confirmed the script gets the value? Does the value get passed to the controller? There are so many places this could go south that you'll need to provide the specifics of the issue to get assistance.

Comment: Apologizes for not being more specific, learning as well how to use this site. my first answer is: my js is wrong. it should be:          
                                                         
    $(document).ready(function () {$('#search-now').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { "search": $('#prodId').val() },
            url: '/Search/Find',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
            });
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

there were a lot of issues with my code, sometimes capitalization,  other times code where code did not need to be.  so far I have success in the way that I am now returning results as html to my console, now to just get that to display instead of being written to console.